# What does "L", "[" and ";" mean in smali code?

Tags: java, android, smali

I'm trying to get a deep understanding of smali language. I found a page talking about opcodes online, but it never talks about these special symbols, which is `L`, `;` and `[`, e.g

```
invoke-static {v2, v3}, Ljava/lang/String;->format(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

So, what does these symbols mean here? e.g `[Ljava/lang/Object;` and `Ljava/lang/String;`

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ cool font

Comment: And I find it hard to locate the duplicated question when I asked about it. Since the former poster does java and I do RE

Comment: This format for dex types is defined in the http://s.android.com/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html document.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[Ljava.lang.Object;` is the String returned from [`Object#String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) for an `Object` array class, similarly for `String`

`[` signifies an array

`L` signifies a class or interface

`;` is end of type

[`Class#getName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29)

```
Element Type         Encoding
boolean              Z
byte                 B
char                 C
class or interface   Lclassname;
double               D
float                F
int                  I
long                 J
short                S
```

Comment: Thanks Reimeus, and what does two consecutive object mean? e.g `format(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)`

Comment: It means you have 2 arrays

Comment: Oh I get it, there's no separator between two objects that pass in as arguments